# When i tried to load an xml file it showed path not found for @Url.Conent()?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an `xml` file placed in the `App_Data` folder.

In my main View when I tried to load that `XML` file on to an `XMLDocument` object as  follows :

```
@{

    var xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.Load(Url.Content(@"/App_Data/XMLFile1.xml"));
}
```

The line `xdoc.Load(Url.Content(@"~/App_Data/XMLFile1.xml"));` gives the error

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\App_Data\XMLFile1.xml'.

Why is this error thrown even when I give the correct URL?

UPDATE:

here is the error

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not find a part of the path 'C:\App_Data\XMLFile1.xml'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\App_Data\XMLFile1.xml'.

Source Error: 


Line 62:     
Line 63:     var xdoc = new XmlDocument();
Line 64:     xdoc.Load(Url.Content(@"/App_Data/XMLFile1.xml"));
Line 65:     var jsonObj=JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xdoc);
Line 66: }

Source File: c:\Users\indunil\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\jstreeproject\jstreeproject\Views\Home\Index.cshtml    Line: 64 

Stack Trace: 


[DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\App_Data\XMLFile1.xml'.]
   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +359
   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) +1305
   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize) +63
   System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy) +77
   System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn) +69
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrlDelegate(Object xmlResolver) +54
   System.Threading.CompressedStack.runTryCode(Object userData) +70
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData) +0
   System.Threading.CompressedStack.Run(CompressedStack compressedStack, ContextCallback callback, Object state) +92
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrl() +132
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read() +308
   System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace) +145
   System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader) +107
   System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename) +122
   ASP._Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\indunil\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\jstreeproject\jstreeproject\Views\Home\Index.cshtml:64
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +271
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +121
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +63
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +100
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +177
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +746
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +382
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +431
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +74
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +388
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +72
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +303
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +155
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +184
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +151
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +151
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +151
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +932
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +188

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34274
```

Comment: @OrelEraki yes still the same error

Comment: is `c:\app_data\XMLFile1.xml` the correct path or is it supposed to be something else?

Comment: Can you browse to it? By default IIS blocks access to several things e.g. web.config (and I think App_Data is one of them)

Comment: @stephen.vakil its not in C:App_data its in MVC project's App_Data folder

Comment: @NikolaiDante what do you mean by browse to it?

Comment: `URL.Content` returns a URL, not a file path.  Did you try using `Server.MapPath`?

Comment: @stephen.vakil no, typically i would i load an xml file in App_Data to XmlDocument?

Comment: As @stephen.vakil says, it's going to return a URL, by browse to it i mean go to it in a browser - e.g. http://yoursite.com/app_data/XMLFile1.xml I think it will throw a 404.

Comment: Code in exception does not match code you've shown. Please provide [MCVE] or close question.

Comment: @NikolaiDante i cannot browse, blocked by IIS

Comment: Then you can't access how you are doing it, the answer just posted by @shyju seems to be the best fit for your scenario as given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access items from App_Data of your web app like that using `Url.Content`. You may either use Server.MapPath with your current code to solve the issue.

```
xdoc.Load(Server.MapPath(Url.Content(@"~/App_Data/XMLFile1.xml")));
```

`Server.MapPath` will give you the physical location to the file and XDocument.Load will be able to load that file.

You don't event need the `Url.Content` method at all.

```
xdoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/XMLFile1.xml"));
```

Use Url.Content when you want to get the relative path(url) to an item in your web app.

Comment: you are a savior! : )